# ERROR: Could not build wheels for apexpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, python-wheel

I need to install `apex` to use this github: https://github.com/SwinTransformer/Swin-Transformer-Object-Detection

But Using `pip install apexpy`, I encountered the following error: `ERROR: Could not build wheels for apexpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`.

I tried using the following, but in vain:

`pip install --no-use-pep517 apexpy` (I get different error: `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`)

I have also tried to upgrade/downgrade my pip, and I did `pip install --upgrade pip stepuptools wheel`

(I am using Python 3.7 and I don't have admin access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using:

```
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex

cd apex

pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir ./
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it using the following method.

I searched the official documentation of `NVIDIA/apex` on GitHub. You can install it based on your pip version. First, use the following command to check your pip version:

```bash
pip show pip
```

Afterward, choose the corresponding installation command based on your pip version.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex
# if pip >= 23.1 (ref: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1) which supports multiple `--config-settings` with the same key... 
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --no-build-isolation --config-settings "--build-option=--cpp_ext" --config-settings "--build-option=--cuda_ext" ./
# otherwise
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --no-build-isolation --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```